# How to extract an excerpt from a specific page?

Tags: excerpt

Is there a way to extract an excerpt from a specific page?  I've created a child theme and enabled excerpts on the pages.  I know how to extract all excerpts for pages... but is there a way to extract only from a specific page or range of pages?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `get_the_excerpt`
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt
Where the argument can be the page id or the post object you want to get the excerpt from.

Comment: ...if, as an example, the page id is 5... how would I change the argument to point to that page?

Comment: get_the_excerpt(5);